# UITapGestureRecognizer on UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have subclassed UITableViewCell and added UITextField to that cell, for UITextField I removed all gesture recognizers (because of becoming first responder after one tap) and added UITapGestureRecognizer which called after tripple tap

```
- (void)tappedOnTitle:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"triple");
    [titleField canBecomeFirstResponder];
}
```

then my `UITextField` (titleField) delegate gets asked

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    return YES;
}
```

it always return yes, but keyboard does not shows (both method are called).

My question is how to activate editing only on tripple tap?

Comment: you are calling `canBecomeFirstResponder` not `becomeFirstResponder`

Answer (score 0):

Use `becomeFirstResponder` instead of `canBecomeFirstResponder`

`becomeFirstResponder` only notifies the receiver that it is about to become first responder in its window.

`canBecomeFirstResponder` returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver can become first responder.

```
- (void)tappedOnTitle:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    [titleField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```